# Error when adding bandit command to MakeFile : make: *** [bandit] Error 1

Tags: makefile, github-actions, bandit-python

I would like to incorporate Bandit security tests into my current Python project and add the command to my MakeFile.

In my Makefile, I added the following code:

```
.PHONY: bandit
bandit:
    pip install bandit && bandit -c pyproject.toml -r . --confidence-level high -f json -q
```

When I run the commands `pip install bandit` and `bandit -c pyproject.toml -r . --confidence-level high -f json -q` in my project directory, there are no errors and the output is as expected. However, when I place it into the Makefile and run `make bandit`, I receive the error of `make: *** [bandit] Error 1`.

Why am I receiving this error? As I am adding the `make` command to my Github Actions file, this also causes an error in the Actions pipeline.

Besides the error message, the output is what I am expecting and is correct. I receive a bandit report on my command line.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The way make works is it runs your command in a shell and waits for it to exit.  When your command exits, make looks at the exit code and if it's success (`0`) then it believes that the command worked.  if it's failure (anything that's not `0`) then it believes the command failed.

In your example:

```
make: *** [bandit] Error 1
```

means that make invoked the recipe for the target `bandit`, and that recipe exited with an exit code of `1`, not `0`, so make considers it failed.  If you ran the command from the shell and printed its exit code:

```
$ pip install bandit && bandit -c pyproject.toml -r . --confidence-level high -f json -q
$ echo $?
```

you'll see it prints `1` as the exit code, not `0`.

I can't explain why your `bandit` command is not exiting with success.  If you can't change that you can "trick" make into believing that it succeeded anyway by adding another command that succeeds, like:

```
.PHONY: bandit
bandit:
        pip install bandit && bandit -c pyproject.toml -r . --confidence-level high -f json -q; true
```

This is a bad idea though, because it means if your command really *does* fail make won't know.  Better is to figure out how to make the command succeed (exit with `0`).